# Commenting selected parts in Sublime (plain text)

Tags: comments

Sorry, is there is a way to comment out selected text in Sublime while using Plain Text (.txt files)?

I've tried adding hotkey command in Settings -> Key Bindings, but it didn't work, I presume there are syntax specific settings for plain text, but I can't find them.
Any suggestions will be highly appreicated.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Comments only really make sense in an environment where you need to distinguish between executable or lets say computer-processed vs. human-processed content. As `.txt` files are not meant to contain executable code or configuration which has to be read by a computer and a human, there is no such thing defined for this file format. AFAIK there's no file specification for `.txt` files as such. They are just text files. Though there probably are thousands of definitions of what exactly constitutes a (plain) text file.

Comment: As a more practical idea: If you just want the convenience of using a shortcut to prefix some lines with some character(s) you can switch the file type in your editor (in VS Code you can select that, not sure on to do it in Sublime) to a file format that has comments.

Comment: Thank you! I've changed it to Bash type, and that worked. Can work with text there while have a possibility to comment out parts of it. Thanks again.